# How to click on the first google search result on google using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on it using this

```
result = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a/h3")))
result.click()
```

But I am not getting any errors and it doesn't click as well. How to click on the first search result on google with python selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first result is always the first `<h3> tag` you can use (this example goes to google.com enters "test" and clicks on the first result):

```
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')

time.sleep(3)

google = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')))
google.send_keys('test')

time.sleep(1)

google.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(3)

result = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('h3')
result.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

To click on the first *Google Search Result* instead of `visibility_of_element_located()` you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the **`element_to_be_clickable()`** and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.google.com")
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  element.send_keys("selenium")
  element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "div#search div.g > div.rc > div.r > a"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.google.com")
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  element.send_keys("selenium")
  element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='search']//div[@class='g']/div[@class='rc']/div[@class='r']/a"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
I can share java code (logic is same ) what I am doing is open chrome and type as"**Testing**" and store all results and and picking the "**Testing Types**" from list

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.List;

public class googleresults {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/justinlambert/Documents/Selenium_Projects/day2/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Testing");

        driver.findElement(By.id("block-517e9e97-d25b-41b1-8108-463e0137df8c")).sendKeys("text");
        List<WebElement> results=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li/descendant::div[@class='sbl1']"));
        System.out.println(results.size());
        for (int i=0;i<results.size();i++)
        {
            if (results.get(i).getText().contains("testing  types"))
            {
                results.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testresults() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a Java way.**

```
import com.automation.DriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

    public class GSearch {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
            WebDriver driver = DriverManager.getChromeDriver();
    
            driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
            //Set search parameters
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search']")).sendKeys("Selenium Testing");
            //Click on Google search button
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='FPdoLc tfB0Bf']//input[@class='gNO89b']")).click();
            //wait sometimes
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            //click google first search result
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rso']/child::div[@class='hlcw0c'][1]/div[1]/div[@class='tF2Cxc']/div[@class='yuRUbf']/a")).click();
            //wait sometimes
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            //close the browser
            driver.close();
    
        }
    }
```